# Как получить URL текущей вкладки Google Chrome и текст на этой странице?

Tags: python, google-chrome, pywinauto

Задача следующая: для автоматизации отдельных рабочих процессов мне нужен телеграм-бот, который по нажатию клавиши будет отвечать ссылкой на текущую вкладку в Google Chrome и текстом, содержащимся в одном из элементов открытой страницы.
Реализую на Python 3.10.8. ОС: Windows 10.

Проблема возникла как раз со считыванием URL и текста из браузера. Получилось найти примеры с использованием модуля [uiautomation](https://github.com/yinkaisheng/Python-UIAutomation-for-Windows), но они не работают, а имеющаяся документация, к сожалению, слишком сложная для моего понимания.

*Как я могу вытянуть ссылку и текст из текущей вкладки Chrome? Что в этом может помочь?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался.
Воспользовался библиотекой pywinauto, чтобы получить ссылку из открытой вкладки Google Chrome.

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

def url_grabber():
        chrome = Desktop(backend="uia").windows(title_re=".* Google Chrome$")[0]
        url_line = chrome.descendants(title='Адресная строка и строка поиска')[0]
        url = 'https://' + url_line.get_value()
        return url
```

Ну а имея ссылку, нужный текст со страницы достал с помощью Requests и Beautiful Soup.